# Browser: Identifier X has already been declared

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 with Babel in my project and I am getting an error when I declare one of my `const`

```
'use strict';

const APP = window.APP = window.APP || {};
const _ = window._;

APP.personalCard = (function () {

   ...

}());
```

the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Identifier 'APP' has already been declared

and that is the whole file, I don't have that declare anywhere else in that file. But I have declared that var in the top of the other files.

What do you think it should be ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> But I have declared that var in the top of the other files.

That's the problem. After all, this makes multiple declarations for the same name in the same (global) scope - which will throw an error with `const`.

Instead, use `var`, use only one declaration in your main file, or only assign to `window.APP` exclusively.
Or use ES6 modules right away, and let your module bundler/loader deal with exposing them as expected.

Answer (score 6):

I had a very close issue but in my case, it was `Identifier 'e' has already been declared`.

In my case caused because of using `try {} catch (e) { var e = ... }` where letter `e` is generated via minifier (uglifier).

So better solution could be use `catch(ex){}` (`ex` as an `Exception`)

Hope somebody who searched with the similar question could find this question helpful.

Comment: Better solution for your case would be to fix the bug in the minifier :-)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `window` is the global namespace. These two lines attempt to declare the same variable:

```
window.APP = { ... }
const APP = window.APP
```

The second definition is not allowed in `strict` mode (enabled with `'use strict'` at the top of your file).

To fix the problem, simply remove the `const APP =` declaration. The variable will still be accessible, as it belongs to the global namespace.

Comment: `window.APP =` is an assignment, not a declaration. It's not even executed before the variable is declared.

Comment: This isn't quite strictly true. Globally-scoped let/const declarations in a real ES6 environment do not add a property to the global object but they do create global-scoped bindings.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error was due to a double import: I was importing my script both at the `<head>` and at the `<body>`, so when the second script was called the variable was already declared. It's a simple mistake but it I hope someone find it useful

Comment: Exact same thing happened to me. Deleting it so that it only had the single script tag under the html's head tag fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

> For those using next.js and having issues with a js Script file after
> a route change.

I'm using a custom-file.js file in next.js and to resolve `SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared` error, simply change your `const` and `let` variables to `var` in your custom-file.js.

If your `<Script src="custom-file.js" />` in next.js loads but doesn't fire after page navigation.

**Solution:**

You should force the file to restart after a page route.

A simple trick from next.js Script is to add a query string at the end of your URL. This will force Next.js to send a new request, forcing the file to restart.

**Here is an example:**

```
<Script async src={`/assets/js/custom-file.js?v=${something-dynamic}`} />
```

This was my fix.

Change your `const` & `let` variables to `var` instead and make your Script src URL dynamic

hope it helps you too..