# Is there any reason to use var anymore?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ECMAScript 6 introduced `let` and `const` keywords for variable declaration.

That being said, is there any reason to use `var` to declare a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is backwards compatibility. Other than that, not that I can see. So if you are using a transpiler then really no point in using var. Unless you need a global variable but that is evil.

Comment: Also against, it, but I recommend writing `window.myVar` if you need a global. It's harder to miss that way.

Comment: @SamR Not everyone uses JS in the browser, and even there there's not always a `window`.

Comment: @Bergi That's true. I tend to focus on client-side. You can create a global with `let` in any environment, so even then you don't need `var`.

Comment: @SamR A problem with that is that [`let`/`const` variables cannot be declared multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36140252/1048572), which is often desirable for global variables.

Answer (score 4):

Backwards compatibility (writing/maintaining ES5) or the ability to write/maintain sloppy code.

`var`, unlike `let` or `const` can redefine a variable multiple times in the same scope. Particularly if you are refactoring something that was already a mess, you might need to stick with `var` for a little while.

There is plenty of code out there that redefines `i` in multiple `for` loops, which would throw an error if you replace one instance with `let`.

This is something that linting tools have been able to catch for years, but that doesn't mean all the sketchy code out there went away.