# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '[x]' has already been declared - why?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, es6-promise

I'm writing some recursive JavaScript code which also uses timeouts.  The purpose is to wait a bit, execute some code, then call the function again:

```
function executeAIMoves(states, curStateIdx) {
  console.log(curStateIdx)
  if (gameOver()) {
    endDemo();
  } else {
    demoTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      makeBetterAIMove(states[curStateIdx], states[curStateIdx+1]).then(bool => {
        executeAIstates(states, curStateIdx+1);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(`error executing ai moves: ${err.message}`)
      })
    }, demoDelay);
  }
}
```

I've searched my directory for 'curStateIdx' and it only appears in this function.  I don't ever 'declare' it with let or const, it's just the name of the argument.  The first time this function gets called, I pass a value of 0, but it doesn't even make it to the `console.log()`.  Most of the stuff I'm seeing on SO about this error is people using `let` or `const` in weird ways, but I'm confused because I don't think I actually declare this variable AT ALL.

Few things to note:

1. I'm using http-server (I require something at the top of `script.js` so I was running into CORS errors).  The tag in my HTML is `<script type="module" src="script.js" defer></script>`
2. The console still shows the error even if I comment out the entire JS file; the only thing that removed the error is if I completely remove the script tag from the HTML.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: The error message should tell you what line it happened on.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140252/browser-identifier-x-has-already-been-declared)

Comment: @Barmar exact error message is ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'curStateIdx' has already been declared```.  It happens on the first line of the function, whether or not the console log is there.

Comment: There should be no problem inside functions, even if you had the same identifier. Have to tried renaming it inside this function? Or what do you see when you halt execution right before the error?

Answer (score 3):

The parameter which will go to "curStateIdx" if it's variable is declared somehow with let or const should be var. I changed to var in my case it worked.

Comment: you are right man, your solution saved my sitation

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadIshaq you're mostly welcome! Happy to be helpful :)